# Getting rid of hover icon in bokeh toolbar

Tags: python, bokeh, toolbar

I want to get rid of the hover icons coming up int the bokeh toolbar for a plot and trying the code below.

```
current_toolbars = plot.toolbar.__getattribute__('tools')
toolbars_to_retain = []
for toolbar_item in current_toolbars :
    if isinstance(toolbar_item, HoverTool) and some_other_condition_for_hover_tool :
       pass
    else :
       toolbars_to_retain.append(toolbar_item)

plot.toolbar.__setattribute__('tools', toolbars_to_retain)
```

But problem is, after doing this the whole toolbar for the plot crashes

Comment: Do you want to remove _just_ the icons or the hover functionality as well?

Comment: @EugenePakhomov Just the hove icons

Comment: @cool_heisenberg please see answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63526003/remove-toolbar-item-in-bokeh-python

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide custom CSS for that. Note that this way of hiding an icon is fragile - it can break with any Bokeh update because it relies on the undocumented parts of the implementation.

```py
from bokeh.core.templates import FILE
from bokeh.io import save
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure(tools='hover')
p.circle(0, 0, size=100)

template = FILE.environment.from_string("""\
{% extends "file.html" %}
{% block postamble %}
<style>
.bk-toolbar-button.bk-tool-icon-hover {
    display: none;
}
</style>
{% endblock %}
""")

# Cannot use `show` because it doesn't accept a template.
save(p, template=template)
```